# Jquery mobile - saving scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

So I just have a quick question.  I have a listbox that pops up a view that fills the screen.  Once the view is dismissed, the window scrolls up back to the top.  Does anyone know how to disable this behavior, or save the mouse position so I can `silentScroll()` back to it after the popover disappears?  Thanks

---

I have this bit in the head to disable the native browser menus for dropdowns and the like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
            $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
        });     
</script>
```

Comment: sounds like an anchor tag being clicked.  If it is, just add `onclick="return false;"` to the `<a>`.  Otherwise we need to see more code to better answer your question.

Comment: There is no anchor tag.  It's part of the Jquery mobile default framework.  It's basically the menu that comes up when I press the dropdown to populate it.

Comment: rats... I haven't worked with jQery mobile... sorry I can't help much :(

Comment: Haha, it's cool  :)  I appreciate the help anyways.  If I could just find a way to save the scroll position when the form is covered, and then silent scroll it back there after the popover is dismissed, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved the problem by doing this in the "pagehide" method:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

and then this in the "pageshow" method:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```

Hope that helps someone.